# Save dictionary values into django model like DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have dictionary values then i want dictionary values into django database model. traditionally we use like

```
Dic = {'id':1,'name':'shiva'}
Data=Model(id=dic['id'], name=dic['name'])
data.save()
```

So here i want save dictionary values similar DRF Serializer concept not like above

```
ModelSerializer(dic)
ModelSerializer.save()
```

How i can implement ,to prevent assigning field values while saving data

Answer (score 1):

use decomposition python asterix,

```
ModelSerializer(**dic)
```